# HTML module in python

Tags: html, python-2.7

I am trying to execute this example code using Python2.7 and it is throwing me error as

'module' object has no attribute 'table'. Can any one help me regarding the correct html module.

```
    import html
    file = open('1.html', 'w') 
    table_data = [
    ['S.No',   'test1 - role'],
    ['1',       'a',         'b'],
    ['2',       'c',         'd'],

    ]
    htmlcode = html.table(table_data)
    c=htmlcode
    print htmlcode
    file.writelines(c)
```

Comment: I realise this is an old thread, but it looks to me like the OP was looking at [this documentation](https://www.decalage.info/python/html) but trying to use [this package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html), which don't appear to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an instance of the HTML class, not use it from the module itself. Like so:

```
from html import HTML
body = HTML()
```

Then you can do

```
body.table(...)
```

p.s.Note that doing body.table(table_data) will not work as you expect it to. I suggest you learn a little how to operate the html library you are using

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
from html import HTML
h = HTML()
h.table(table_data)
```

See the [package information](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html) for more details.

Comment: Ya i did that too but its throwing "ImportError: cannot import name HTML". I installed the package fom this [package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html)

Comment: i am not able to find in particular the HTML.py for Py2.7

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably 7 years 6 months late, but there's actually a library for this very purpose called Sierra.

Just do `pip install sierra`

You can check out their [documentation](https://brainstormyourwayin.github.io/sierra.github.io/). I've actually used it for quite a bit now, and I must say it's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
import html
file = open('1.html', 'w') 
table_data = [
['S.No',   'test1 - role'],
['1',       'a',         'b'],
['2',       'c',         'd'],

]
htmlcode = html.table(table_data)
c=htmlcode
print htmlcode
file.writelines(c)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!